# Swiper wrapper didn't update when I update swiper instance (Swiper JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have four buttons to show/hide slide card based on user selection. I show all products by default in total 10 cards. When changed to other options (the slide that only have four cards), there is a white space left. I tried to update with $productSlider.update() but it didn't work.

[Demo Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-glitter-1locd?file=/index.html) (codesandbox)

**Swiper Init**

```
let $productSlider = new Swiper('.plan-slider-container', {
  init: false,
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  observeSlideChildren: true,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
    forceToAxis: true
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  keyboard: true,
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    draggable: true,
    hide: false,
  },
  breakpoints: {
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
    },
    768: {
      freeMode: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto'
    }
  }
});
```

**User Selection Button**

```
$('.choice-plan-btn-wrapper.desktop').on('click', e => {
  let target = e.target;
  let id = target.getAttribute('id');
  let $parent = $(target).parent();
  let lastActiveSiblingId = $(target).siblings('.active').attr('id');

  if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'button' || target.classList.contains('active')) return;

  // button
  $(target).addClass('active')
           .siblings('.active').removeClass('active');

  /* The Problem */
  $parent.siblings('.plans-swiper-wrapper')
         .children(`.${id}`).fadeIn('slow')
         .siblings().not(`.${id}`).fadeOut('slow');
  
  $productSlider.update();
  /* The Problem */
  
  $parent.siblings('.swiper-scrollbar')
         .removeClass(`${lastActiveSiblingId}`)
         .addClass(`${id}`)

  $productSlider.slideTo(0, 500);
});
```

[image: Product Slider]

Comment: Can you create demo code with html ?

Comment: @Swati https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-glitter-1locd?file=/index.html

Comment: so when you reached on last slide..it should again start from 1 ?

Comment: @Swati I think you might confused what I explain. Sorry for my English tho. I have total four slides. Say each one is 200px (So Wrapper is 800px wide). When I choose the options from dropdown, it only show related slide for the option. Let's say 2 slides. So wrapper might be 400px wide. The thing is the wrapper didn't wide when i call mySwiperInstance.update() but when I rotate the device (using chrome dev console) the wrapper size is updated.